# Possible to route based on condition in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular7, angular-routing, angular8

I have dynamic configurations for routing in angular applications as like below.

```
 { path: ':locale/:id', component: HomePageCategory    },
 { path: ':locale/:platform', component: PlatformPageCategory    },
 { path: ':locale/contact', component: ContactPageCategory    },
```

In above code i have navigate based on dynamic value. if 2nd url comes as number means it should go to one component and its comes as string means it should go other component. based on this only it should route. its my requirement. is this possible to implement.

> its possible to route condition based?

For additionally condition based routing is supported or not? as like ASPNET Core. please check the below images.

[ASP.NET Core Routing constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMTJ6.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via a canActivate. In the canActivate check the type of the routeParam and redirect it accordingly to another route of your wish.

I made a stackBlitz example right here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-pux5el?file=app/my-guard.guard.ts

Comment: Hi @Udi, i have tried but when i route programatically means it always tooks 1st router config only.  i can't able to call 2nd router programatically. can you please share any idea about this.

Comment: I made a stackBlitz example. If you write a string it will go to string component and if you write a number it will go to number component.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-pux5el?file=app/my-guard.guard.ts

Comment: Hi,  can you please check the image, thats what i needed in angular.... https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMTJ6.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to implement this in the paths description. Something you can do is **refactor your paths** and make then have **different number of params**. Then you can make a workaround when you have to navigate to your route.

Example:

```
if (isNaN(parseInt(yourParam))){
   // This is not a number, navigate to route 1
} else {
   // This is a number, navigate to route 2
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gabryel, i have tried but when i route programatically means it always tooks 1st router config only. i can't able to call 2nd router programatically. can you please share any idea about this.